# Render Partial using Collection @Array and Object @Item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having NilClass Error while i am trying to do this

```
 $("#profile-list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'partial', collection: @items, object: @item) %>");
```

Error in partial: @item is nill

my all code in partial is using **@item** that's why i need to send single **@item** from array of **@items**.

Note: @items array is not null i checked.

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose. Where is `@item` being created?

Comment: I updated my question. I have '@items' in action but i want to send each element in form of '@item' not in ':item' because partial have '@item' everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: you cannot control the instance variables in that way you're attempting. The best you can do is control the name of the local variable, like so:

```
<%= render partial: "partial", collection: @item, as: :something_else %>
```

And your partial will have access to an local variable called `something_else`, rather than `item`, as is normal. But you cannot cause the partial to create an instance variable called `@item` or `@something_else`.

Technically speaking, partials have access to all instance variables in the entire view environment. Therefore they would have access to `@items` (or one called `@item` if you manually created one). However that approach is excessively and unnecessarily complicated and verbose (when there are shorter alternatives), as you would need to manually iterate over the collection, set the `@item` variable, and render the specified partial.

The highly recommended approach is to simply alter the partial, and change all instances of `@item` to simply `item`. Bear in mind that partials should be capable of existing on their own, without relying on the existence of instance variables set by the calling environment.

Your render line should then look like this:

```
$("#profile-list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'partial', collection: @items) %>");
```